# Two definitions of Strong Markov property for Brownian motion

Tags: probability, analysis, stochastic-processes

Strong Markov property for Brownian motion:

> (Def 1)For every almost surely finite stopping time $T$, the process
> $$\{B(T+t)-B(T): t\geq 0\}$$
> is a standard Brownian motion independent of $\mathcal{F}(T)$.

> (Def 2) $$\mathbb{E}_x[f(B(t))|\mathcal{F}(T)]=\mathbb{E}_{B(T)}[f(B(t-T))]$$
> on ${T\leq t}$.

Why are these two definitions of SMP equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $2$ to $1$:

Let $V=(V_t) = (B_{T+t} - B_t)$ be that process, let $A \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R^{[0,\infty)})$ (in cylinder $\sigma-$field). Let $A_0 = \{ x \in \mathbb R^{[0,\infty)} : x-x(0) \in A \}$ ( we translate every function in $A$ by minus it's value at $0$). Note that:

$$ \mathbb P_x( V \in A | \mathcal F(T)) = \mathbb P_x( (B_{T+t} - B_T) \in A | \mathcal F(T)) =  \mathbb P_x ( (B_{T+t}) \in A_0 | \mathcal F(T))$$
(since $B_T$ is value at $0$ of process $(B_{T+t})_{t \ge 0}$. Now apply $2$, getting:
$$ \mathbb P_x ( (B_{T+t}) \in A_0 | \mathcal F(T)) = \mathbb P_{B_T}( (B_t) \in A_0) $$

Note that for any $y \in \mathbb R$ we have:
$$ \mathbb P_y( (B_t) \in A_0 ) = \mathbb P_y( (B_t - y) \in A) = \mathbb P_0 ( (B_t) \in A) $$

Taking $y = B_T$ it finally gives us:

$$ \mathbb P_x( V \in A | \mathcal F(T)) = \mathbb P_0 ( (B_t) \in A) $$

in particular $$ \mathbb P_x (V \in A) = \mathbb E_x[\mathbb P_x(V \in A |\mathcal F(T))]= \mathbb P_0( ( B_t) \in A) $$
so we showed that $V$ has the same distribution (under $\mathbb P_x$ measure) as standard brownian motion $(B_t)$ (cause it's under $\mathbb P_0$ measure))

Now to show independence, Take any $B \in \mathcal F(T)$ we get:

$$ \mathbb P_x(B \cap \{ V \in A\}) = \mathbb E_x [ 1_B \mathbb P_0 ( (B_t) \in A)) = \mathbb P_x(B)\mathbb P_0( (B_t) \in A) = \mathbb P_x(B)\mathbb P_x( V \in A) $$

From 1 to 2:

$$\mathbb E_x [ f(B_{T+t}) | \mathcal F(T)] = \mathbb E_x [ f(B_{T+t} - B_{T} + B_{T}) | \mathcal F(T)]   $$

I don't know what information you possess, but it can be shown that as adapted, right continuous process, Brownian Motion is progresivelly measurable, hence $B_T$ is $\mathcal F(T)$ measurable. By 1. we have that $B_{T+t} - B_T$ is independent of $\mathcal F(T)$ so by conditional expected value property, the last one is equal to:
$$ \mathbb E_x[ f(B_{T+t} - B_T + p)] |_{p = B_T} $$
Again using $1$, we know that $B_{T+t} - B_T$ under $\mathbb P_x$ is distributed as standard (so under $\mathbb P_0$) brownian motion, so:
$$  \mathbb E_x[ f(B_{T+t} - B_T + p)] |_{p = B_T} = \mathbb E_0 [ f(B_t + p)]|_{p = B_T} = \mathbb E_p[f(B_t)]|_{p =B_T} = \mathbb E_{B_T}[f(B_t)]$$

So we proved $\mathbb E_x [ f(B_{T+t}) | \mathcal F(T)] = \mathbb E_{B_T}[f(B_t)]$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But how to understand $ \mathbb E_{B_T}[f(B_t)]$? Which are averaged over there?

Comment: Exaclty as $Y=\mathbb E_{B_T}[f(B_t)]$ is a random variable given by $Y(\omega) = \mathbb E_{B_{T(\omega)}(\omega)}[f(B_t)]$. So you average $f(B_t)$ under $\mathbb P_x$ measure but when $x$ is somehow random, that is in point $\omega$ it is $B_{T(\omega)}(\omega)$

Comment: How to apply $2$ getting:
$\mathbb P_x ( (B_{T+t}) \in A_0 | \mathcal F(T)) = \mathbb P_{B_T}( (B_t) \in A_0)$?

Comment: apply $2$ with function $f= 1_{A_0}$ (indicator function of set $A_0$).

Comment: I just want to ask if I am correct for applying the def 2. Can I just let $f(B_t)=1_{\{B_t>0\}}$? Then we have $P_x(B_t>0)|\mathcal{F}(T))=P_{B(T)}(B_{t-T}>0)$ on $\{T\leq t\}$ by applying Def 2?

Comment: Exactly, but I prefer to use $\mathbb E_x[f(B_{T+t})|\mathcal F(T)] = \mathbb E_{B_T}[f(B_t)]$ instead of your formulation of $2$, since it doesn't require $\{ T \le t\}$

Comment: So $f$ can be any bounded measurable function? How about if I let $f(B_t)=1_{\{B_t-h_t>0\}}$ where $h_t$ is some functions about $t$. Or $f(B_t)$ is only about $B_t$ but not other functions. Also, If I let $x=B_T$, is it still $E_{B_T}(f(B_{T+t})|\mathcal{F}(T))=E_{B_T}(f(B_t))?$ Thanks.

Comment: $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a bounded measurable function. $f(B_t)$ is just a shorthand for random variable $f(B_t(\omega))$ (so you plug point $B_t(\omega)$ in function $f$). Note $f$ does not depend on $t$! It is $B_t$ which depends on $t$. For the second question, It is important that $x$ is not random in that formula, so you can't use it with random variable $B_T$ (in fact this formula shows what those two things have in common).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dominik!

Comment: Sorry, just double check I am right. Can I let $f(B_t)=1_{\{B_t-h_t\geq 0\}}$?

Comment: No, you cant define $f(B_t)$. You can define $f(x) = ... $ and then plug $B_t$ in that formula. So you can't have $h_t$ which depends on $t$. You can for fixed number $h$ have $f(x) = 1_{\{x-h \ge 0\}}$ and then $f(B_t) = 1_{\{B_t - h \ge 0\}}$